# How to tag a branch for release?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I created a repo in github and cloned it in my local machine. then i created a development branch in my local machine and then pushed it ( sample below). i want to create a feature branch from the development and once merged to development , i want to create/tag it for a release which gets merge to master. do i need extensions like gitflow for that or can i do that without?

I haven't tried the gitflow extension yet.

```
git checkout -b development
git push origin development
```

Comment: Your description is a bit muddled, and suggests you've not yet got the hand of what tags and branches are. We all have to start somewhere, but in this case you're probably better off finding an "introduction to git" online (there are plenty of them out there).

Comment: Note that in Git, you do not (cannot!) tag a *branch*. You tag a *commit*. There are multiple reasons for this, including the fact that branch names don't matter, are potentially different in every clone, and can be completely deleted (so that your tagged commit is on *no* branch). It takes a little getting used to.

Comment: @torek - thanks. I've read it somewhere that commits are tagged and then that version is released. so when we commit to a master branch, is it simply tagging it and then just making sure no more commits are done to that main/master branch before we release?

Comment: @kyagu: pretty much, yes. In a previous life, our practice was to create a release branch (rather than using the master branch), make commits to it to prep the release, tag one of those as "release candidate alpha" or whatever was appropriate, run that through the next phase, etc. When we got a candidate approved we'd add the release tag to that specific version. That's not the only way to do this, but it leaves an easy path for adding features to the RCs or backing them out as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an annotated tag in Git is simple. The easiest way is to specify `-a` when you run the `tag` command:

```
$ git tag -a v1.4 -m "my version 1.4"
$ git tag
v0.1
v1.3
v1.4
```

The `-m` specifies a tagging message, which is stored with the tag. If you don’t specify a message for an annotated tag, Git launches your editor so you can type it in.

You can see the tag data along with the commit that was tagged by using the `git show` command:

```
$ git show v1.4
tag v1.4
Tagger: Ben Straub <ben@straub.cc>
Date:   Sat May 3 20:19:12 2014 -0700

my version 1.4

commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    Change version number
```

Comment: thank you. curious, if you don't mind, can i follow gitflow like workflow without using gitflow extension?

Comment: Yes you can. Gitflow is really just an abstract idea of a git workflow. It make you easier to use git workflow, because gitflow have a documentation and shorcut.